# How to connect remote repository in JFrog Artifactory to repo.manento.com?

Tags: composer-php, magento2, artifactory

Is possible to add repo.magento.com as a remote repository to Jfrog Artifactory?
I added repo.magento.com as remote php repo but when I try to require a module like "magento/product-community-edition" in the Artifactory logs I see the error

```
Error occurred while parsing the response of a remote composer package JSON query on 'https://repo.magento.com/p/magento.json': Expected a file but found a folder, at: php-magento:.composer/p/magento.json
```

This occurs because repo.magento.com doesn't use lazy url but explicit all packages in https://repo.magento.com/packages.json.

There is any way to customize Artifactory packages.json to prevent lazy url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked to jFrog support and they answer me

> Currently Artifactory does not support repo.magento.com.

I created and issue on JFrog Jira https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-18169